# add foreign key attribute in the owner class?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have this simple entity class in a spring boot app:

```
@Entity
public class Plant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String code;
    private String location;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="companyid", nullable = false)
    private Company company;
}
```

This represents a plant. A company can have one or more plants and one plant can belong just to one company. In the postgresql db the `plant` table was created with a `companyid` foreign key field referrencing to the `id` field of the `company` table. Fine.

Now, my question is: do I have to add the `companyid` attribute to the `plant` class? If yes, with `transient` annotation? Because the field is already in the database because of the `company` relationship.

Later if I will send a post request to this backend f. e. to create a new plant, I can send a whole `company` object, but just only the `companyid` too.

What is the right way to model this? What is the standard? I remember, in EF core if I have referrenced a navigation property I added the according `id` attribute (aka foreign key) to the model class too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The association setup looks correct, with JPA you do not explicitly create a foreign-key attribute (you would not even necessarily need the `@JoinColumn` annotation if you are fine with the default behavior).

For creating a REST-API, one standard approach would be to map the Entity to DTOs for sending data from and to the API. Depending on the (endpoint-specific) use-case, a DTO might e.g. only contain `id`s of associated entities instead of the whole entity.
Tools like `mapstruct` enable the simple generation of corresponding mapping code.

Another idea to reduce some boilerplate would be to use a framework like `spring-data-rest` which automatically creates a REST-API from the defined entity classes:
https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest